# make edittext place in the middle using canvas and drawable

Tags: android, xml

I learned about how to create an OTP from drawable using canvas. [OTP screen](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/building-a-pinentryedittext-in-android-5f2eddcae5d3)
But I want to have a box instead of a plane lines at the bottom, and I want to have the text in the middle of the box, instead of 8 dp above the line. I made a few modification like adding a rectf and drawing using canvas. It was easy. But It will not be responsive on all the screens.

```
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            //super.onDraw(canvas);
            int availableWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
            int availableHeight= getHeight()-getPaddingTop()-getPaddingBottom();

            if (mSpace < 0) {
                mCharSize = (availableWidth / (mNumChars * 2 - 1));
            } else {
                mCharSize = (availableWidth - (mSpace * (mNumChars - 1))) / mNumChars;
            }

            int startX = getPaddingLeft();
            int bottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom();

            //Text Width
            Editable text = getText();
            int textLength = text.length();
            float[] textWidths = new float[textLength];
            getPaint().getTextWidths(getText(), 0, textLength, textWidths);
             Paint mPaint = new Paint();

            RectF rectF;
            int cornerRadius = 15;
            for (int i = 0; i < mNumChars; i++) {




                mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorViews));
                mPaint.setAlpha(70);
                mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

                rectF = new RectF(startX, availableHeight, startX + (int) mCharSize, bottom);

                canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF,cornerRadius,cornerRadius,mPaint);

    //            canvas.drawLine(startX, bottom, startX + mCharSize, bottom, mPaint);

                if (getText().length() > i) {
                    float middle = startX + mCharSize / 2;

                    //y= bottom-mLineSpacing
                    canvas.drawText(text, i, i + 1, middle - textWidths[0] / 2, bottom-mLineSpacing, getPaint());
                }

                if (mSpace < 0) {
                    startX += mCharSize * 2;
                } else {
                    startX += mCharSize + mSpace;
                }
            }
        }
```

And my  xml file looks something like this

```
<com.example.android.EditTextOTP

      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:cursorVisible="false"
      android:digits="1234567890"
      android:inputType="number"
      android:maxLength="4"
      android:textIsSelectable="false"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:paddingStart="40dp"
      android:paddingEnd="40dp"
      android:paddingTop="60dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_otp_text"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gl_inside_bg"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/gl_vertical_end"
      android:id="@+id/et_otp_box"
      >


  </com.example.android.EditTextOTP>
```

The above way works fine but I want to place the number as I type in the center of the BOX. not roughly on the top of the BOX. How can I improve this?